# How to align text in the middle of two ${hr}s?

Tags: conky

I wanted to have two horizontal green lines on either side of the label for the sections of my conky, but when I try and do that, I get the green line taking up the entire horizontal space and no space for the text. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

The conky is in very early stages of development, and I just ran into this problem, so there isn't much there. Here's the .conkyrc:

```
alignment tr
use_xft true
xftfont Droid Serif Bold:size=9
double_buffer true
gap_x 10
gap_y 10

color1 afafaf
color2 00ff00
color3 0a0a0a

TEXT
${color2}${hr}${color1}.: INFO :.${color2}${hr}
${color2}${kernel} ${color1}${machine}
```

Also, just while we're at it, i've been getting a syntax error from conky at the `alignment tr` line. It says this:

```
conky: Syntax error (/home/ricky/.conkyrc:1: syntax error near 'tr') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference, but it's odd that it would do that.

Comment: you can't do that , because the hr meant to have one parametr 'height' `${hr height} !      you can control only the offset where the hr begins like `${offset 200} INFO ${hr 2}`

Comment: @clearkimura The version is 1.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull off something close to what you want like this...

```
${alignc}Some Text
${color green}${voffset -25}____________${alignr}____________
```

...which results in something like this...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have two issues here: using two `${hr}` and syntax error `near 'tr'`.

### Using two `${hr}`

Insert a text between two horizontal lines? You can't do that using `${hr}` object. You can only control the height of line in pixels (as pointed out in the comment above).

I'd suggest to use **underscore** `'_'` to draw the two lines instead, like below.

```
TEXT
${color2}__________${color1}.: INFO :.${color2}__________
${color2}${kernel} ${color1}${machine}
```

In above code, I have used 10 underscores for each line. Using this many of underscores could fit the first line of TEXT within a width of 200 pixels.

### Syntax error `near 'tr'`

As Conky version 1.9, the `alignment` variable still can accept two-letter positioning i.e. `tr` by default. However, from version 1.10 and onwards, it seems that the default rule has been restricted to using only the full variable i.e. `top_right` instead of `tr`.

[This forum thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=24054.0) reveals that Manjaro users had the same issue recently.

> After some confusion and searching I finally found out about the new syntax Conky expects from version 1.10
>   Unfortunately 'man conky' points you to a non-existent directory .
>   The example file you will find here: `/usr/share/doc/conky-1.10.0/conky.conf`
>
> ```
> conky.config = {
>    alignment = 'top_left',
>    background = false,
> ...
> }
> conky.text = [[
> ${scroll 16 $nodename - $sysname $kernel on $machine | }
> ...
> ]]
> ```

### Syntax error itself

Besides the full variable, using old syntax with Conky 1.10 is likely the reason to throw the error. As such, consider rewriting your `conkyrc` file using new syntax like below.

> ```
> conky.config = {
>    alignment = 'top_right',
>    use_xft = true,
>    xftfont = 'Droid Serif Bold:size=9',
>    double_buffer = true,
>    gap_x = 10,
>    gap_y = 10,
>    color1 = 'afafaf',
>    color2 = '00ff00',
>    color3 = '0a0a0a'
> }
> conky.text = [[
> ${color2}__________${color1}.: INFO :.${color2}__________
> ${color2}${kernel} ${color1}${machine}
> ]]
> ```

[This post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1540862#p1540862) on different forum thread had mentioned some clues on how to rewrite old syntax into new syntax for Conky 1.10 or newer.

Comment: Sadly, the syntax error doesn't go away when i substitute `tr` for `top_right`. The only thing that changes is that is says `syntax error near 'top_right'`, as apposed to `tr`. Not that big of a problem anyways. Thanks. I'll try the underscore thing.

Comment: @MintyChipp Updated my answer. I just realized that it is not just the full variable issue. Conky 1.10 is using new syntax for its configuration file.